# Yii2: How to select multiple fields from different tables

Tags: mysql, yii2

My tables

```
Category
id_category
name

Post
id_post
category_id
title
```

My query:

```
Post::find()
->select('post.*, c.name AS catname')
->leftJoin('category c', 'c.id_category = category_id')
->all();
```

The output just shown the table fields *Post*, is not the field *catname*.

Comment: Show the code related to the query and the output please

Comment: "Getting unknown property: app\models\Post::catname"
I have "$posts = Post::find()..." and error is at line:
"foreach ($posts as $post) {
$post->catname;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Define a relation in Post model named 'category', so:

```
public function getCategory() { 
     return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id_category' => 'category_id']); 
}
```

2) Then when you query the posts, use 'with' if you need to get category name for each post:

```
$posts = Post::find()
->with('category')
->all();
```

3) You can access to category name with:

```
$post->category->name
```